# stacking dataset using "for loop" function in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm having a trouble answering a homework question.

Create a larger dataset by stacking `gm2`
`n=100` times over. That is, if `nrg` is the number
of rows of `gm2` and `ncg` is the number of columns,
the larger dataset should have `100*nrg` rows and
`ncg` columns.
Call your stacked dataset `biggm2`. 
To create the stacked dataset, 
initialize with `biggm2 <- NULL` and use 
a `for` loop to build up `biggm2` one layer 
at a time. Time this code using the `system.time()` function.
An example use of `system.time()` to time an R 
command, e.g., `x <- rnorm(100000)` is:

Code given:

```
system.time(
{
  x <- rnorm(100000) # Could put multiple lines of R code here
})
```

I am new to R and this is taking too much time to find the answer. Hence, I'm asking this question here.

I'm using library(gapminder)

To add, 'gm2' is a dataset:
The columns `year`, `lifeExp`, `pop` and 
`gdpPercap` and save this dataset as `gm2`.
Also coerce `gm2` to a matrix and save as `gm3`.

This is what I did to read the dataset. Is this correct?

```
gm2 <- c(CanUS2$year, CanUS2$lifeExp, CanUS2$pop, CanUS2$gbpPercap)
gm2
gm3 <- matrix(gm2, nrow=24, ncol=4)
gm3
```

Or is this correct?

```
gm2 <- subset(CanUS2, select = c("year","lifeExp","pop","gdpPercap"))
```

But here, there is no point of coercing to a matrix since gm2 is already a matrix.

```
gm3 <- matrix(gm2v, nrow=24, ncol=4)
gm3
```

I am really confused.
Any advice will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please learn to use `code` sections in your questions.

Comment: Why are you trying to code in R like you would in a crude language like Python or Java?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(gapminder)
```

Tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(gapminder, country %in% c("United States", "Canada")) %>%
  select(year, lifeExp, pop, gdpPercap) -> tidyverse_can_us

head(tidyverse_can_us)
## # A tibble: 6 × 4
##    year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
##   <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
## 1  1952   68.75 14785584  11367.16
## 2  1957   69.96 17010154  12489.95
## 3  1962   71.30 18985849  13462.49
## 4  1967   72.13 20819767  16076.59
## 5  1972   72.88 22284500  18970.57
## 6  1977   74.21 23796400  22090.88
```

Base R:

```
gapminder[with(gapminder, country %in% c("United States", "Canada")),
          c("year", "lifeExp", "pop", "gdpPercap")] -> base_r_can_us

head(base_r_can_us)
## # A tibble: 6 × 4
##    year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
##   <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
## 1  1952   68.75 14785584  11367.16
## 2  1957   69.96 17010154  12489.95
## 3  1962   71.30 18985849  13462.49
## 4  1967   72.13 20819767  16076.59
## 5  1972   72.88 22284500  18970.57
## 6  1977   74.21 23796400  22090.88
```

For either of those you've lost the factor variable that ties the values to the country. We also have no idea why you want/need a matrix. I made the assumption you were extracting Canada & U.S. data from your variable name but your entire question was mostly incoherent so it's hard to know what data you have and what outcome you want/need.